# Release version doesn't connect to googple play service

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-play-services

Hi everyone and thanks for hearing me out.

I have an app that I build using Google play games, Google play services, ETC... Basically the debug version works perfectly fine and connected to multiple devices, however the release version can't sign in to google play games and causes the app to crash when attempting to do anything that requires it.

I suspect this is an issue with the authentication, but I tried using the developer console to create a new OAuth2.0 that has the package name and the fingerprint of the keystore that I'm using for release and it still dosen't work.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you checked crash log from your google play account?

Comment: @Piyush I know what's going on. It fails to sign in. The crash it the lesser important part here as it's just a by-product

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is with the authentication issue . First of all make sure you have the proper release key . This [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) will walk you through to get the fingerprint, and then in your google play console under your game services select linked apps and link your release version here

[image]

If still doesn't  connect to the google play service, please provide your log then I can find the best solution for you